# Why my flags did not counted?

Tags: support, flagging

I have raised too many flags as **duplicate**;
but this is a long time that none of my flags has been counted;
not as a helpful flag nor as a disputed/declined/retracted flag.

For example see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2427543/proving-that-e-set-of-even-integers-is-equal-to-f-sum-of-two-odd-integers)

Comment: Use your new found powers wisely :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you reached 3000 points of rep you earned [the privilege](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) to **vote** to close posts. Congratulations! This means that whenever you flag a post to be closed, the system automatically converts that flag to a vote. Therefore such a flag never existed.

See the following passage from that Help Center page

> Note that once you gain the reputation to vote to close, you should no longer flag for moderator attention to have questions closed or migrated. It is your responsibility to vote now.

See [here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3154/how-should-my-flagging-change-when-i-gain-the-ability-to-vote-to-close) for more.